# Set headers in zf2

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, http-headers, httprequest

i have set up a following headers in my controller, with the following code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
```

how can i achieve this in the zend framework 2,

Thanks

Comment: i have done in the following way, am i right:                                               $resp->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
            'Content-Type' = > 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            'Allow-Methods' = > 'GET, POST'
            'Allow-Origin' = > '*'
        ));

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set custom headers for individual controller actions in ZF2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921295/how-to-set-custom-headers-for-individual-controller-actions-in-zf2)

Comment: Thanks foozy, thats helpful in for other headers to set like, Cache-Control, Pragma and Expires

Answer (score 2):

```
use Zend\Http\Headers;
```

...

```
$headers = new Headers();
```

or

```
$headers = $httpObject->getHeaders();
```

then to add headers one by one

```
$headers->addHeaderLine('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$headers->addHeaderLine('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
$headers->addHeaderLine('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
```

or pass all in one array like this

```
$headers->addHeaders(array(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'
));
```

if you created a new headers object

```
$httpObject->setHeaders($headers);
```

Comment: @markwinkle If you liked my answer it would be great if you would accept it so the question is closed...